# How can I see my favourite question in the Android App?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, bookmarks

How can I see my favourite question in the Android App? I can favourite questions but don't know how to see them.

Comment: Yes, I've read that. The last answer was on 24 Aug 2016, so I thought the feature is already available now..

Comment: There has been next to no development on the Android app in that time unfortunately